# How do I get an android app to auto-update?

Tags: android, auto-update

I'm making an android app that is going to be used privately so I don't want to put it on google play or some other marketplace. My users would download the app from a website I have setup. I want to implement a semi auto update in the form of a button that appears on the main screen when an update to the app is available. So far I can compare the version numbers and even download the new version of the app, but I have the problem that the old version stays downloaded as another application, instead of being deleted or rewritten. Is there a way I can have the old version delete itself after it downloads the new app, or is there a cleaner way to go about this?

Comment: If you are using the same package name, it should overwrite your old version.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the problem that the old version stays downloaded as another application, instead of being deleted or rewritten

That will not occur if your package name remains the same. It is not possible for two apps to be installed at the same time on the same device with the same package name.